# Is it safe to use cat <<-EOF

Tags: bash

```
cat <<-EOF
    #lots of text
EOF
```

This syntax sure makes it simpler to manage lots of lines and also is just a single call to `cat` rather than a bunch of `echo`s.
But is it safe to use `<<-`?

There are many text editor settings that may mess with spaces and tabs and its annoying to keep track of those. (portability is a concern)

Using only `<<` would make the source code look dull without indentation.

Is there any safer and clean way to do this?

I have made a small edit and now it doesn't seem to be opinion based in any way.

Comment: Every editor I am aware of, can be configured to either replace tabs by spaces, or leave them as they are. Most editors can be configured to display, whether white space is tab or a set of spaces. Of course some people (like me) don't want to have hard tabs in their programs, if they can avoid it. There are several alternatives to `cat` of a HERE-document, such as the one proposed by kvantour, but I don't know a single one which would be aesthetically pleasant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should realize that some users set their editors to automatically convert tabs into spaces. So when you work with multiple users on the same script, it is paramount to set up some base rules for this, which is annoying as you will end up with a one-day tab-vs-spaces war. Furthermore, I often consider tabs evil. They are good as a field separator, but they are awful when visualization depends on it. Everything depends on where the tabstops are defined and this can change from editor to editor and terminal to terminal. Sometimes. the tabstops are defined as a multiple of 8, sometimes as a multiple of 4. There is even the Posix command `tabs` which allows you to set the tabstops in any way you want

```
$ tabs 1,6,10,14,18,22,26,30,34,38,42,46,50,54,58,62,67
```

So ... tabs are evil!

My suggestion to you is to use the following:

```
 printf "%s\n" 'fantastic line1' \
               'awesome line2'   \
               'amazing line3'   \
               'unrivaled line4'
```

Comment: Sorry, this is a bit an opinion based question, but I could not place this in a comment.